# Get object from HashMap which contains key substring

Tags: java

I have a Map object which has `COM-20 HELLO` as key and `My name` as value.

Is there any way to get this object by indicating that I want the key that contains `COM-20` without the `HELLO`

Thanks.

Comment: Post some of your source code.

Comment: No, there is no direct way to do this using just a hashmap.  A hashmap can only be searched using exact keys, not approximate ones.  In your case, a B-tree would allow such searching (this data structure is often used in databases).

Comment: ..and even a B-tree won't be helpful unless you're looking for Strings *starting* with a specific sequence.

Comment: @Kayaman Well, there are also things like R-trees, but I get your point ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there are a lot of beautiful data structures :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys should be unique, if you have a map with keys like: COM-20 HELLO1 and COM-20 HELLO2
what should it return? both of them? It is not possible.

Comment: I know there won't be two keys with COM-20 as it's a pair ID-TITLE